# Protecting querystring variable for use in SQL query parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security

I'm writing a simple website that will act as a discussion board/forums in vb.net.

When a user clicks on a forum, the forum id is put in a querystring variable that the "Topic" page reads and then collects all topics with that forum ID. Likewise, when a user clicks on a topic, the post page will collect all posts with that topic ID.

IE:

```
F_ID = Request.Querystring("F_Num")
myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Forum_Topics WHERE Forum_ID = @ID", myConnection)
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", F_ID)
```

My question is:

While I use the id as a parameter in a SQL query, what should I do to the ID in the variable before or after using it or passing it to a page for purposes of security?

Are there best practices governing using querystring to transport data from page to page?

And lastly, is there a different method I should use if this one is not secure enough?

For purposes of this question, as long as a user is logged in (handled elsewhere) they are allowed to see any and all topics.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is too broad.  See faq.  I will however point you to https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page.  There are so many issues here.  Is it ok for folks to just switch the ID on the query string... can all users be allowed to see ID xyz.  How do you prevent one user from seeing id=123 by manipulating the URL ... etc.

Comment: I edited my post to make it a little less broad. Seeing any and all topics or posts is not an issue. I'll definitely look through that link though.